# Spark Metrics not viewable in VisualVM

Tags: apache-spark, jmx, metrics, visualvm, spark-submit

I am trying see the spark metrics after configuring the metrics.properties file. This is the command I am using for spark submit -

> /home/spark/spark/bin/spark-submit --class SparkRunner --master
>   spark://x.x.x.x:7077 --files /home/spark/spark/conf/metrics.properties
>   --conf spark.default.parallelism=96 --conf spark.metrics.conf=/home/spark/spark/conf/metrics.properties --conf
>   "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9099" x.jar

I can connect VisualVM on port 9099 from my local machine. But I am unable to get the metrics in MBeans. All I see are java.lang or java.util.logging MBeans. 
I have uncommented the jmx sink line form my metrics.properties. What am I doing wrong?